# systemd service -- wait for vbox mount of shared folder

Tags: systemd, virtualbox, services

On a VBox VM I have a service that monitors the `ip` status for changes. Joining a VPN for example.

The working script requires access to a path on a VBox shared folder mounted at `/mnt/host`. This mount shows up in systemd's service list as `mnt-host.mount`  I assume.

```
systemctl list-units | grep mount
...
mnt-host.mount    loaded active mounted   mnt-host.mount 
...
```

In the service definition, I ask systemd to wait for this mount before running my network-monitor service:

```
[Unit]
Description=monitor network
After=mnt-host.mount


[Service]
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/network-monitor.sh
       
[Install]
WantedBy=default.target
```

However this is not working. The service startup fails because the required directory is not mounted yet. Once the VM startup is completed, I can restart the service and all is well, however I really want the service to start without my help.

Comment: Also ran into this issue, did you ever figure it out?